# Why in calculus do we substitute say $x$ for $a$ in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Like, $x$ never equals $a$ and yet we just substitute the value in in the limit.

For the proof of the power rule, we want to show that $$lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$$ exists. A typical proof in single-variable calc tells us that we have [image]

Why can we substitute $x$ for $a$ when $x$ can never equal $a$, although it can get arbitrarily close? Please use delta/epsilon arguments because this doesn't make any sense to me despite the intuition that $x=a$ in the limit. Still, it's not entirely clear at all to me why the limit is $na^{n-1}$.

Also, how do you figure out what the derivative is a priori? Like, to prove this, we have an error in the output of size $\frac{1}{m}$ and we want to compare our derivative at $x_0$ with all values $\frac{1}{n}$ away from $x_0$ in the domain and make sure all outputs are $\frac{1}{m}$ away at most. But to compare something with something else, you need to know the values of the thing you're comparing. So in this case, how do you find the value of the derivative?

Comment: It's not just substituting in $a$ for $x$ at an arbitrary point.  It's using a theorem about limits: that $\lim_{x\rightarrow y} x^n = y^n$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Okay, I think the problem is that my textbook didn't define limit laws, only limit laws when $x \to \infty$

Comment: What textbook do you use? Any decent textbook should tell you how to find the limit of the sum or product of two functions as $x\to a$ if both functions have a finite limit as $x\to a.$

Comment: In general we **cannot** just put $a$ in the place of each $x$ in the limit; there need to be specific reasons that allow us to do that. The way I've seen this done is to prove a few theorems such as the limit of a sum or product and apply these to build theorems for more complicated combinations of functions. This way you get a lot of limits for the cost of just a few delta-epsilon proofs early on.

Comment: Sometimes $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=a$ and sometimes $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\ne f(a)$. If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=a$ we say such a function is **continuous at a**.  That is a definition.  Polynomials are continuous at all points and the text has proven that earlier and is assuming you remember that.  It's very convenient as it *feels* like we can substitute (which is easy) but we can't always. We can only do it for continuous functions. The trick is proving when a function actually *is* continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Why in calculus do we substitute say x
> for a
> in the limit?"

We don't and we can't.  We can only do so for functions that we have *previously* shown we can.  And your text has previously shown that polynomials are just such a function.

(Such a function is called *continuous* which means nothing more or less than for every $a\in R$ we have $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.)

==========

ts;du (too short; didn't understand)......

It's a good question and shows you are thinking critically.

Your text has already proven that if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist then $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x) + g(x))= \lim_{x\to a}f(x)+\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$[1] and $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)[2]$.

And it's trivial to prove $\lim_{x\to a} x = a$.  (Pf: for all $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta =\epsilon$.  If $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|x-a| < \delta = \epsilon$.)

And it's even *more* trivial to prove $\lim_{x\to a} c = c$ (for a constant $c$) (Pf: for all $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta =$ anything positive.  If $|x-a| < \delta$ then $|c-c| = 0 < \epsilon$.)

So $\lim_{x\to a} x^2 = \lim_{x\to a} x\cdot x$ and as $\lim_{x\to a} =a$ then $\lim_{x_a}x\cdot x = \lim_{x_a}x\cdot \lim_{x_a}x = a\cdot a = a^2$.

And by induction if $\lim_{x\to a}x^{n-1}=a^{n-1}$ then  $\lim_{x\to a}x^n =\lim_{x\to a}x^{n-1}\cdot x=\lim_{x\to a}x^{n-1}\cdot\lim_{x\to a} x=a^{n-1}\cdot a = a^n$.

And therefore for any constant $c$ we have $\lim_{x\to a} cx^n = \lim_{x\to a} c\cdot\lim_{x\to a} x^n = cx^n$.

And therefore for any polynomial $p(x) = c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.... + c_1x + c_0$ then $\lim_{x\to a}p(x)=\lim_{x\to a}(c_nx^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+.... + c_1x + c_0) = \lim_{x\to a}c_n\lim_{x\to a}x^n + \lim_{x\to a}c_{n-1}\lim_{x\to a}x^{n-1}+.... + \lim_{x\to a}c_1\lim_{x\to a}x + \lim_{x\to a}c_0=$
$c_na^n + c_{n-1}a^{n-1} + .....c_1a + c_0 =p(a)$.

And *that* is why we can assume that $\lim_{x\to a}p(x) = p(a)$ *when p(x) is a polynomial*.

And so..........It all works

$(x^n-a^n) = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a +......... + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1})$ so

$\frac {x^n-a^n}{x-a} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a +......... + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$ which is a polynomial (the $a$s are constants)

As $x^{n-1} + x^{n-1}a +......... + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$ is a polynomial we know that we can "substitute $x=a$" when taking a limit.  So;

$f'(a) =\lim_{x\to a}\frac {x^n-a}{x-a} =$

$\lim_{x\to a}(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a +......... + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1})=$
$a^{n-1} + a^{n-1}a +......... + aa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}$

And then $a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}a +......... + aa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}=\underbrace{a^{n-1}+a^{n-1} + ..... +a^{n-1} + a^{n-1}}_{n\text{ times}}=na^{n-1}$

======

[1] Suppose $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=N$.  Then for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\frac 12 \epsilon > 0$ and so there is a $\delta_f$ so that when $|x-a|< \delta_f$ we will have $|f(x)-M|<\frac 12 \epsilon$ and there is a $\delta_g$ so that when $|x-a|<\delta_g$ we will have $|g(x)-N|<\frac 12\epsilon$.  Therefore if $|x-a| < \min(\delta_f,\delta_g)$ then $|(f(x)+g(x))-(M+N)| = |(f(x)-M)+(g(x)-N)|\le |f(x)-M| + |g(x)-N|< \frac 12 \epsilon +\frac 12 \epsilon=\epsilon$.

[2] We can prove that $\lim_{x\to a}Nf(x) = NM$ (Pf: If $N=0$ there is nothing to prove.  If $N\ne 0$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ then $\frac\epsilon{|N|} > 0$ and there is a $\delta$ so then $|x-a| \implies |f(x)-M| < \frac {\epsilon }{|N|}\implies |N||f(x)-M|=|Nf(x)-NM|< \epsilon$)

And we can prove $\lim_{x\to a}-Mg(x)=-NM$ (Pf: ditto with a slight addition that $|g(x)-N| = |-g(x) -(-N)|$)

Which means $\lim_{x\to a}Nf(x)-Mg(x)=\lim_{x\to a}Nf(x) + \lim_{x\to a}-Mg(x)=NM+(-NM)=0$.

Now $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =M$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=N$  so for any $\epsilon > 0$ there are $\delta_f,\delta_g, \delta_0$ so that $|x-a|<\min(\delta_f, \delta_g,\delta_0)$ implies $|f(x)-M|<\sqrt{\frac 12\epsilon}, |g(x)-N|< \sqrt{\frac 12\epsilon}$ and $|Nf(x)-Mg(x)| < \frac 14\epsilon$.

$|f(x)g(x) -MN| =|(f(x)-M)(g(x)-N)+M(g(x)-N) + N(f(x)-M)|\le$
$|f(x)-M||g(x)-N| +|Mg(x)-NM| + |Nf(x)-NM| < \sqrt{\frac 12\epsilon}\sqrt{\frac 12\epsilon} + \frac 14\epsilon +\frac 14\epsilon = \epsilon$.

Comment: Wow, this answer is amazing. I'm in analysis right now, and though I learned about limit laws back in Calc BC, I'm questioning everything slightly more. This cleared it up!

Answer (score 1):

We have a theorem, or if you like to say, an equivalent definition for continuous function:

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a),$$ if $f$ is a continuous function and $a$ is in the definition domain of $f$.

I think you doubt the third equation in your post. Just pick $f$ as $x^{n-1}+...+a^{n-1}$ and put it in the above theorem, and then you'll see why.

Comment: I think this attempted answer is a bit question-begging: how do we know the function is continuous? What we really require is theorems, not definitions.

Comment: It is a polynomial. Is proof of the continuity of polynomials what you want?

Comment: If it is so, the answer from @messenger is really a good way to show it.
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4571773/488919

Comment: For most circumstances, it is sufficient simply to mention that it is a polynomial. My only misgiving is that it's not clear whether OP has yet learned that all polynomials are continuous.

Comment: Well, I think it answers the OP's question.  The OP asks "why doe we substitute $x$ with $a$ in limits when they are different values" and the answer is "we don't and we can't; we only do it for functions that we have previous shown we could; a polynomial is a class of functions that we have earlier shown we could"

Answer (score 1):

In this example what you need is that any polynomial function is continuous.  You could build that up from showing the continuity of
$$f(x) = x$$
from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, and then using (proving if need be) algebra of limits (limit of sums, limit of products).

Answer (score 1):

The function under the limit has a removable discontinuity at $x = a$, and we can remove it by cancelling $x - a$ in the numerator and denominator. With other types of discontinuities such as infinite discontinuities or oscillating discontinuities, we cannot remove the discontinuity.

So now our function is continuous and hence we can use the fact that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$, as others have mentioned.